# Birch trees with peeling bark and black area on trunks

Tags: trees, diagnosis

I am wondering about my trees in our front yard. They seem to be peeling much more than others in the neighborhood and have black patches on the trunk. Any info on what I should do?

[image][image][image]

Comment: Are these areas wet? These could be Cankers.

Comment: Check if the areas are soggy or soft - it does indeed look like possible gummosis or canker and the tree may be compromised.

Comment: They dont seem to be wet to the touch.   What would be the solution to this if t they are

Comment: @Tim Young well that's the funny thing about birch.. their supposed to have black spots. That being said, if those spots seem: gummy, wet or squishy (like rot) then the prognosis is grim (canker disease). This time go back to the wound and smell it. I know that sounds odd but smell it and tell me if it smells like disease (you will know). In this situation you are just going to have to trust your judgment is it diseased or not?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inonotus_obliquus ?

Comment: Possibly useful background:  Birches, especially landscape cultivars, are well out on the life-fast-die-young end of the tree spectrum.  Like aspens they are highly susceptible to all manner of diseases.  Pamper them along but don't blame yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a fungal infection of Chaga (medicinal mushroom) which is a black canker that grows slowly on Birch trees. You can learn more about it here " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inonotus_obliquus "